# Error when releasing QByteArray

Tags: c++, qt

My QbyteArray variable is crashing when destroyed.

The Qbytearray is a member variable (not a pointer variable) of a class, when I destroy the class I got this error. Is there anything I can do to fix it? Or maybe I do it wrong?

I am using Ubuntu 16.04 and Qt 5.7.0

Here the error info when I debug it :

[image]

[image: Error Qbytearray]

Comment: What is the actual error text? Your question would be much more accessible if you had your code included as text rather than an image.

Comment: I am not on my machine now, I will update it next 8 hours

Comment: I am just asking, If this is not a pointer variable, why do you need manual allocation and deallocation for it?

Comment: Use valgrind to get more diagnostics.

Comment: @t.m I don't allocate or deallocate the QByteArray, it get deallocate automatically when I destroy my class

Comment: @michalWalenciak : Valgrind does not help at all, it get crashes also

Comment: Apin: valgrind crashes?! Could you show output?

Comment: @michalwalenciak : it says "valgrind stop". Anyway, I have fixed it another way around, because I don't know what to do.